# Hyperledger Fabric byfn.sh script Failed Loading Certificates

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

OS: Windows 10 Home Version 2004 64-bit

Docker Version: 19.03.8

docker-compose version: 1.25.5

When bringing up the network using ./byfn.sh up, I've encountered multiple errors loading certificates in channel creation, joining peers, and querying chaincode on peers. Anyone experience this issue and solved it?

```
2020-06-10 03:49:03.416 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 001 Failed loading ClientOU certificate at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: open /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
2020-06-10 03:49:03.418 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 002 Failed loading PeerOU certificate at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: open /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
2020-06-10 03:49:03.419 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 003 Failed loading AdminOU certificate at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: open /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
2020-06-10 03:49:03.421 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 004 Failed loading OrdererOU certificate at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: open /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path description is invalid in terms of linux container environment. Instead of `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts\ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem` it should be:

`/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/cacerts/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem`

The given path is relatively specified in the `config.yaml` file for every MSP that is created. You can verify it there. Also, make sure that you have not changed the default docker-compose files. Otherwise, the docker volume mounts will not work correctly unless properly modified.

Please perform a `./byfn.sh down` and then start the network again with `./byfn.sh up`.

Comment: Hello Chintan, thank you for the fast response. I performed ./byfn.sh down and restarted the network, but the certificates still fails to load and the same error still appears.

I have also checked the config.yaml file for both MSP and this is what's inside one of them:
NodeOUs:
  Enable: true
  ClientOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: client
...


By the way I am using Windows 10 Version 2004 and Docker version 19.03.8

Comment: Please set the following environment variable `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1` in the windows environment variables or create a `.env` file in the `fabric-samples/first-network` directory and write the above variable inside it.

Comment: I've set that in the environment variables settings but the same error appears.

Comment: Please try making use of Linux environment. You can use Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) for Windows environment. It works very good for HLF at least. Because there are several issues one might face in configuring HLF with Windows alone.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Used wsl 2 and enabled the docker wsl 2 backend and it worked like a charm.